# Passing multiple array in v-for

Tags: vuejs2, v-for

I just wonder if its possible to pass data like this:

```
  <tr v-for="item1 in items1">
      <tr v-for="item in items">
          <td><label>@{{ item.id }}</label></td>
          <td><label>@{{ item.name }}</label></td>
          <td><label>@{{ item.age }}</label></td>
          <td><label>@{{ item.profession }}</label></td>
          <td><label>@{{ item1.approval }}</label></td>
          <td><label>@{{ item1.request }}</label></td>                
      </tr>
  </tr>
```

in **JS**

```
 data: {
    items: [],
    items1:[],
   },
  mounted: function mounted() {
    this.getVueItems();
  },
  methods: {
    getVueItems: function getVueItems() {
      var _this = this;

      axios.get('/vueitems').then(function (response) {
        alert(response.data);
        _this.items = response.data;
        _this.items1 = response.data;
      })
      .catch(response => {
        alert("WTF happen!?");
      });
```

I want to know is this possible. Or is there any other options?.

Comment: My only problem is i want to add other data into v-for loop. Its like a php foreach inside foreach

Comment: Definitely possible, although you'll probably want to use `<template v-for="item1 in items1">` for the outer loop. Otherwise, you'll have a `<tr>` element for each `item1` containing the `<tr>` elements for each `item` in `items`.

Comment: @thanksd .always thank you.

Comment: @thanksd .would you mind to send my a sample fiddle?. Because i have other loops here that has more than 2 needed. sample my object masterIds and detailsIds. and getting what is inside.

Comment: Here's a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/6hazwkf9/

Comment: @thanksd u're the best. I just want to ask. why it loop twice?. do i need to put conditions?. so that it won't loop twice?.

Comment: @chimichi004 because 2*2 =4; you can try to use one computed property to reshape the data first, then uses one `v-for` to reach the goal. Inside computed property, do something like `array1 join array2`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I don't really understand what you're trying to do if the tabling having four rows is unexpected. The loop inside the outer loop means that `items` will be looped over once per `item1` in `items1`. Since there are two entries in `items1`, the `v-for="item in items"` loop happens twice.

Comment: I thinks thats considerable. Thank you so much..